# How to concatenate two hex values into one in SAP2 assembly?

Tags: assembly

I’m learning assembly and I need to do the following:

User enters 4 hex digits. First two concatenated to make an 8 bit number. Second two concatenated to make a second 8 bit number. Add up the two 8 bit numbers and display the 8 bit result.

Using assembly instructions for SAP2
Any help?

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. Please post an attempted solution. If the solution does not work, describe how the incorrect results differ from the desired results. Excellent guidelines here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Cheers!

Comment: Your hex digits already *are* concatenated, you just need to convert them to an 8-bit integer.  The normal way is `first_digit * base + second_digit`, after you do ASCII->integer conversion for each digit.  A lookup table can be handy for hex because the low 4 bits aren't continuous (there's a gap from 0..9 to a..f)

Comment: Ok so how would a user enter 4 inputs? and How would i combine first 2 in one and the second 2 in second one?